# error: unexpected exception No module named pydevd

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to use PyDev with Eclipse. However when i start to debug my code, i get this No module found error.

My code is

```
global _initialized, _path, _version
# ADD THE FOLLOWING TO LINES WHERE YOU WANT TO BREAK
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=5678)
# execution will stop at this line    
if _initialized and _path != path and _version != version:
    ERROR_HANDLER('Attempt to reconfigure with different path')
```

The error I get is

```
error: unexpected exception
    No module named pydevd
```

Sorry, I am new to Eclipse and only working on python for 2 months. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure `pydevd` is in your PYTHONPATH environment variable. This can be set through the OS or by adding it using `sys.path`:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/pydevd.py')
```

File path of pydevd is usually something like:
eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_x.x.x/pysrc/pydevd.py